# Python class inheritence isn't giving me separate instances of a list

Tags: python, subclass

I don't understand what is going on here. I have a class "C" that is a subclass of "B". "B" has an attribute "b" which is an instance of class "A". "A" has one attribute, a list called "a". When I initialize two different instances of "C", they have the same instance of "A" such that when I append to A.a it results in both instances of "C" having an appended attribute "b.a".

```
class A:
    a = list()

class B:
    b = A()

class C(B):
    pass

one = C()
two = C()
one.b.a.append('one')
one.b.a.append('two')
two.b.a.append('three')

print(one.b.a)
print(two.b.a)
```

Running this code prints out:

```
['one', 'two', 'three']
['one', 'two', 'three']
```

Clearly, one.b.a and two.b.a are pointing to the same object when I would have expected a new instance of "A" to be initialized whenever I call C(). Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: `A.a` is one list. Not one list per instance, but one list for the whole class. Also `B.b` is one instance of `A` for the whole class `B`. Class variables are different from instance variables, which matters when they refer to mutable objects like lists.

Comment: `B` has a *class* attribute named `b`. You don't have separate lists for each *instance* of `B`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you declared `a` and `b` as class attributes and **NOT** instance variables. You can think of class attributes as global variables for that class. There can only be one value for a class attribute for all objects.

On the the hand, instance variables are unique to each instance of the class. See [this article](https://www.google.com/search?q=class+variable+vs+instance+variable+python&oq=class+variable.vs+instance&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j0l7.6903j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for a more in depth explanation.

To summarize:

```
class A:
    a = 'A'
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 'B'

foo = A()
bar = A()

foo.a
>>> A

bar.a
>>> A

foo.b
>>> B

bar.b
>>> B

A.a = 'C'
foo.a
>>> C
bar.a
>>> C

foo.b = 'D'
bar.b
>>> B
```

Comment: A bit of this code is incorrect. Setting `foo.a = 'C'` would create an instance variable `foo.a`. It would not alter the value of `bar.a`.

Comment: If you want to get the class variable from an instance, you need to call foo.__class__.a.  Setting foo.a, as noted above, just creates an instance variable and doesn't affect bar.

Comment: @khelwood woops, looks like you're right, made an edit

Comment: adding my +1 because I didn't know the difference between class attributes and instance attributes and it was making me go mad!!